# System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type

Tags: c#, object, foreach, .net

I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Holo.Virtual.Rooms.Bots.virtualBot' to type 'Holo.Virtual.Rooms.Bots.virtualRoomBot'.

Here's my code:

```
foreach (virtualRoomBot roomBot in _Bots.Values)  // Exception thrown here
{                    
    if (roomBot.goalX == -1)
        continue;
```

Holo.Virtual.Rooms.Bots.virtualBot contains:

```
public class virtualBot
{
    public virtualBot(int botID)
    {
        DataRow dRow;
        using (DatabaseClient dbClient = Eucalypt.dbManager.GetClient())
        {
            dRow = dbClient.getRow("SELECT * FROM roombots WHERE id = '" + botID + "'");
        }
        *There are values for the db here*
    }
}
```

And Holo.Virtual.Rooms.Bots.virtualRoomBot contains:

```
public class virtualRoomBot
{
    internal virtualRoomBot(int botID, int roomID, int roomUID,
        virtualBot Bot, virtualRoomBotStatusManager statusManager)
    {
        this.botID = botID;
        this.roomID = roomID;
        this.roomUID = roomUID;
        this.Bot = Bot;
        this.statusManager = statusManager;
    }
```

Comment: `virtualBot` and `virtualRoomBot` are two different and unrelated types.  You can't directly cast from one to the other.  If `_Bots.Values` contains a collection of objects of type `virtualBot` then you can't treat it like a collection of objects of type `virtualRoomBot`, which you're trying to do.  Beyond that, it's unclear what it is you're trying to do or where you get `_Bots.Values`.

Answer (score 2):

`_Bots.Values` is a collection of `virtualBot` and your code should be

```
foreach (virtualBot roomBot in _Bots.Values)
{                    
    if (roomBot.goalX == -1)
        continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your `foreach` statement as follows:

```
foreach (virtualBot roomBot in _Bots.Values)
```

Or you could omit the explicit class type and just use the implicit type [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx):

```
foreach (var roomBot in _Bots.Values)
```

I also suspect that since you're specifically testing the value of `roomBox.goalX`, you might actually be iterating on the wrong list altogether. Did you actually mean to iterate on `_Bots.Values` at all? Maybe you have a `_RoomBots.Values`?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
public class A { }
public class B : A { }

A a = new A();
B b = (B)a;
```

This code above will give "Unable to cast object of type 'A' to type 'B'." The same thing is happening to your sample of code.

if you instantiate a `virtualBot`, you can't just cast it to `virtualRoomBot`.

You should make one class inherit the other. Then, do casts in the direction that i show in the code below:

```
public class A { }
public class B : A { }

A a = new B();
B b = (B)a;
```

This should works. Hope it helps.
Best regards